# Print tensorflow Variable throws error

Tags: tensorflow, spyder

I am trying out `Tensorflow` example on `Variables`, however I am getting an error while I try to print using `tf.Session`

```
ValueError: Variable my_int_variable already exists, disallowed. Did 
you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:
```

I am pretty sure I have not defined anywhere else and Removed all variables as well on Spyder

```
import tensorflow as tf

my_int_variable = tf.get_variable("my_int_variable", [1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int32,
  initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(print(my_int_variable))
```

The screen shot of my error
[image]

Comment: You probably meant `print(session.run(my_int_variable))`, and should initialize variables in the session before trying to retrieve their values. Otherwise, the snippet that you included will not produce the error that you mention, so it is hard to tell what is happening in your actual code.

Comment: @jdehesa I've attached the screen-shot

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that if you are getting that error only with that code, there must be something else that you ran before, or maybe you just run the same code twice. If you run the snippet in a new interpreter (e.g. close and reopen Spyder) and run that code once you should not see the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not initialize the variable before using it. Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

my_int_variable = tf.get_variable("my_int_variable", [1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int32,
  initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)

with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(session.run(my_int_variable))
```

It produces the zero-initialized array on my machine. Also, it is good practice to evaluate the variables within the print function.